# Console application - first Message Box is not focused

Tags: vb.net, console-application, messagebox, msgbox

I am in the process of developing a VB.Net console app to get ID & password from users and should pop a message when invalid ID or password is entered, but I am stuck with a peculiar behavior observed while using Message box in console app. When the first message box is shown, its Out-Of-Focus & we explicitly need to bring the message box to focus. But the next subsequent message boxes are In-Focus.

Below is just the sample code.

```
Sub Main()
Start:
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter")
    Console.ReadLine()
    MsgBox("Good Day")
    GoTo Start
End Sub
```

Just want to know why such thing is happening & what should be done so the first message box also will be In-Focus.?

Comment: Why would you display a message box from a Console app?  Yes, it can be done; no, it's not a good idea.  Provide the user with feedback inside the app, i.e. with Console.WriteLine.  Also, get rid of that `GoTo` and **NEVER** use one again.  Why would you not just use a `Do` loop there?

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney thank you for your response. I was using GoTo coz I need to start from the beginning (ask ID & Password again and validate it), so though it would save some line of code. But anyway will keep in mind that I won't use it for any other purpose.

However my question is not to use anything or not, but why the first message box is Out-Of-Focus and the all subsequent message boxes are in focus. If I can someone get the first message box also in focus, then it would resolve my entire problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification` to show the dialog on top.

This is converted from a C# application, so not exactly sure if this is correct VB.NET (it should be though):

```
MsgBox( "Good Day"
      , ""
      , MessageBoxButtons.OK
      , MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk
      , MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1
      , MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification
      )
```

**But note this:**

You shouldn't use a `MessageBox` inside a Console application. These are just two different worlds.

**To explain why:**

What do you expect when you run this application remotely using the console? There is no way to show that messagebox then. Use `Console.WriteLine`, but with different coloring if you want to show something is in error, or a warning, or something good.

Comment: While I'd agree that this is good advice, it's not really an answer to the question as asked so probably ought to be a comment.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your information. But I am aware we are not supposed to mix MsgBox within console application, but I want to use it coz, 1) this application will be used by real end users to input their ID & Password and it will validated before its used for any purpose (sometimes its used to connect to SQL DB, sometimes to check http web-response for a URL) 2) I feel msgbox will be more apt to tell user that the data they've entered is Invalid, rather than just showing it as a message in console.

Comment: Then don't use a Console application, or show a message in the appropriate way.

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks for your valuable time. I tried but MsgBox class takes only 3 parameters 1) string displayed in the message box 2) Button style & 3) string to be displayed in title bar. As of now my only question is why the first message box is coming Out-Of-Focus and the all subsequent message boxes are in focus. If I can somehow get the first message box also in focus, then it would resolve my current problem.

Comment: I don't really know. Hans Passant had an answer explaining more what is going on but he deleted it. Will ask him to undelete it.

Comment: @HansPassant: can you please undelete your question?

Comment: Hi @PatrickHofman, sorry I guess I need to import System.Windows.Forms to use MessageBox rather than MsgBox. And after using MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification I can see the message box is coming with Focus and that resolves my problem. Thank you very much for that.

However I would feel happy if someone explain why the first msgbox is coming always out of focus.